# Google BigQuery "unexpected error"

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using Google BigQuery to store and query data. My query application has been working for a few weeks now. But all of a sudden, without any changes on my side, I am getting an "unexpected error"!

I have logged I to the web query interface to BigQuery, run the same queries, and get the same error message. Not very helpful.

Has Google changed something? Can anyone assist me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add the some example queries which produce the error, it might help someone to analyze your problem.

Comment: "Unexpected error" is almost always a bug in BigQuery. Can you share either the job id of a failed query, or if you don't have that, just your project id?

Comment: Hi Jordan, my project id is coral-bebop-245, do you need me to share it with you? 

I did try to copy a table which is giving me this problem and I got the following error:

"Invalid field name "_2ch". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, have a letter before any digits, and be at most 128 characters long."

The field name seems to fit into the rules specified ?!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Check your quota, or billing limits.

Answer (score 1):

"Unexpected error" is *always* a bug in BigQuery. If you see this, file an issue on the bigquery issue tracker or create a stack overflow question. Be sure to send your job ids (project:job_id) along with what you were doing when you got the error.

In the specific case of the problem hit by the OP:

The _2ch fields were causing a crashing problem in one of the BigQuery backend services. We put in a short-term workaround to make those fields illegal since it was affecting our service stability.

We've fixed the underlying problem, and may relax the check to allow those fields again soon.